# Can a pod have two containers with same image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

For example two redis containers.

Can we do the following?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webserver
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.16-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      - name: redis1
        image: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 891
      - name: redis2
        image: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 789
```

Comment: Please don't try to work around the site quality controls by including gibberish. You could have used that text to say a) whether you've tried this already; b) what the result was.

Comment: (I don't see any reason why you couldn't, but I'd have to try it to be sure - which you can do too.)

Comment: Have you got any error by trying that config. If yes then let us know what error you got.

Comment: Pod status said CrashLoopBackOff and when i checked the logs of the pod it said that internal port already in use

Comment: Is it just a port conflict issue or something else? Doesn't container have their own IP address. So why was there a conflict?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the containers in a pod share same `localhost` hostname. All containers can be reached using pod's IP address. Like on your workstation, if you already have nginx running on port 80, you cannot use the same port for another nginx instance or any other application.
I don't get it why you'd use same image to create two containers. If it's for scaling up the application, you could just scale up using more replicas.

Comment: I'm a noob so please bear with me on this: I just checked and all the containers had different IPs. So why is there a conflict? And about that two images, i was just checking if they work.

Comment: Have a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#networking